# How to hide scrollbar in side navbar?

Tags: css, sidenav

i create side navigation bar and i want when restore down height of my browser , don't see scrollbar at all.

here is my CSS code:

```
.sideNavBar-icon {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60px; 
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6c299b 0, #5ba7b4 99%, #55d6be 10000%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  top:70px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: please do provide html part

Answer (score 1):

You can use this css property `::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display:none;
}`

to the specific class.